# how to compare results in for-loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I created a class, it has some initial variable like coefficient and error. And in my method, I have a for loop to calculate something, in each run, I will get a number which is named as error. And in each run, I got a error and also have a coefficient number. What I want to do is, at the first run, I can get a error and a coefficient set. At the second run, I will compare error with the previous error, if it is smaller than previous one, then, update error to the smaller error, and also update the coefficient. Else, keep the previous error and coefficient.

```
class getMinError():
def __init__(self):
    self.error = 0
    self.ce1 = 0
    self.ce2 = 0 

def process(self):
     for i in range(any number):
        run to get error, ce1,and ce2
        save the first run's result to self.error, self.ce1,and self.ce2
```

or just save it without update to the initial variables.

compare in the next loops, and 
update only when error is smaller than previous ones.

Comment: You can use temporary values to hold the error and coefficient of the current run and make comparisons with the previous values.

Comment: use temp variable for holding or use tuple (error,coefficient) with list and use it tuple[0] , tuple[1] for comparing with previous added tuple in list

Comment: could you guys say more about using temporary variable? I tried that, but as it is in the loop, if I create a new var, it can save the first run's error value,but in the second run, it will update by the execution. like first_error = error, I want to use the first_error in the next loop, like compare if first_error < error, but here, first_error will update to error, it can not compare then.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the result from first run to compare it to the next ones.
Then in each iteration compare the current run's error to the number stored in smallestError (the smallest err found yet). If you find a smaler error than smallestError then do the updations of co-efficienets and error and change smallestError to the recently found error.
Hope this helps :) .

```
class getMinError():
def __init__(self):
    self.error = 0
    self.ce1 = 0
    self.ce2 = 0 

//store the error of first run
run to get error, ce1,and ce2
smallestError = error

def process(self):
     for i in range(2:n):
        run to get error, ce1,and ce2
        if smallestError > error :
           self.error=error
           self.ce1=ce1
           self.ce2=ce2
           smallestError = error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
class getMinError():
def __init__(self):
    self.error = 0
    self.ce1 = 0
    self.ce2 = 0 
 run to get error, ce1,and ce2

def process(self):
     for i in range(2:n):
        run to get error, ce1,and ce2
        if error<self.error :
           self.error=error
           self.ce1=ce1
           self.ce2=ce2
```

Hope that will be helpful .

Comment: the point is that error is always bigger than 0, so if error <self.error will not happen. I must at least save the first run's result and use them to replace the self.error than  I can start running the next ones.

Comment: you forgot to comment that line

Comment: You save the fisrt run's result , and then you start loop on 2 and then apply youre rule